# Bug in getBackgrounds() using custom theme colors

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a spreadsheet with colors from a custom theme.

When I read the colors using getBackgrounds() the colors returned are all #000000
If I read the colors cell-by-cell using getBackground() the colors are returned correctly.

If I use standard colors (ie not colors in my Theme) the colors are also returned correctly.

TEST SHEET
(available to view at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCZeUbCjs_5p6_52v8ggqVgrgnJ-Pd6x-gzXUFfV8G0/edit?usp=sharing

Cells A1:D1 contain the names of the four Beatles, all with background color #b70906

TEST CODE

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
    
    
    function getbackgroundstwoways(){
    var  fullrange= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1:D1");

    // Read all cells using getBackgrounds
    var arBack = fullrange.getBackgrounds();
    var arValues=fullrange.getValues()  
      
    Logger.log("Full array " +arBack + arValues);  
    
    //Now do the cells individually with getBackground
    for (var i=0; i<fullrange.getLastRow();i++){
        for (var j=0; j<fullrange.getLastColumn();j++){
        
        Logger.log("Single cell " + i + " " + j + "  " + fullrange.offset(i,j).getBackground() + " " + fullrange.offset(i,j).getValue() ) ;
        
        }}}
```

LOGGER OUTPUT

```
 Full array #000000,#000000,#000000,#000000John,Paul,George,Ringo
 Single cell 0 0  #b70906 John
 Single cell 0 1  #b70906 Paul
 Single cell 0 2  #b70906 George
 Single cell 0 3  #b70906 Ringo
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer?

### Issue and solution:

When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, the background colors of cells "A1:D1" has the color type of "THEME". I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In the current stage, it seems that `getBackground()` can directly retrieve the background color from the color type of "THEME" as the hex string. But, it seems that `getBackgrounds()` cannot directly retrieve them. The retrieved values using it becomes `#000000`. I'm not sure whether this is the bug or the current specification. But in the current stage, the background colors of the color type of "THEME" can be retrieved by the methods in Spreadsheet service.

One of several solution is to use `getBackground()` as your script. This has already been achieved in your script.

In this answer, as another pattern, the colors are retrieved from the values retrieved by `getThemeColors`. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Create an object for searching the colors from the theme color type.
2. Retrieve background objects.
3. Retrieve the background colors from backgroundObjects.

#### Sample script:

```
function getbackgroundstwoways() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const fullrange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:D1");  // Range from your script.

  // 1. Create an object for searching the colors from the theme color type.
  const theme = ss.getSpreadsheetTheme();
  const themeColorObj = theme.getThemeColors().reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: theme.getConcreteColor(SpreadsheetApp.ThemeColorType[e]).asRgbColor().asHexString()}), {});
//  const fullrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();

  // 2. Retrieve background objects.
  const backgroundObjects = fullrange.getBackgroundObjects();

  // 3. Retrieve the background colors from backgroundObjects.
  const backgroundColors = backgroundObjects.map(r => {
    return r.map(c => {
      if (c.getColorType() == SpreadsheetApp.ColorType.RGB) {
        return c.asRgbColor().asHexString();
      } else if (c.getColorType() == SpreadsheetApp.ColorType.THEME) {
        return themeColorObj[c.asThemeColor().getThemeColorType()];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(backgroundColors);
}
```

- This script can be used for the color types of both "RGB" and "THEME". When this script is run at your shared Spreadsheet, `[ [ '#b70906', '#b70906', '#b70906', '#b70906' ] ]` can be seen at the log.

  - Even when the RGB types and the THEME types are mixed, this script can retrieve the background colors as the hex string.

### Note:

- In this case, the background colors are retrieved from the theme colors. But when you overcoat the background colors as the RGB type of `#b70906`, you can retrieve them using `getBackgrounds()`.
- When I searched about this that `getBackgrounds()` cannot be used for the THEME color type at the issue tracker, I couldn't find this. So how about reporting this? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)
- Please use this script with V8.

### References:

- [getSpreadsheetTheme()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettheme)

  - This method is added at [December 18, 2019](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2019#december_18_2019).
- [Class SpreadsheetTheme](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-theme)
- [getBackgroundObjects()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgroundobjects)

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful and comprehensive reply.

I think this must be a bug on Sheets, and I'll follow it up.

Interestingly, if you add a new Custom Color that is not part of the Theme then getbackgrounds() works OK.

Comment: FYI Google have confirmed they can reproduce this bug in their test environment and so have filed it internally.

Comment: @RIchard Thank you for replying and adding more information. By the way, if my answer was not useful for your situation, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks, Google have acknowledged the problem and are investigating - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157858927 - and if they fix it in a reasonable timeframe then I can wait for that to happen. The routine that I'm writing is part of an onEdit() that gets called very often, so speed is a major consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post useful as there are different cases then you use `colorObject` in Sheets.

Examples of getting color object:

- `range.getBackgroundObjects()`
- `sheet.getTabColorObject()`

Here's the code to convert color object to RGB color:

```
/**
 * Get the HEX-color of sheet
 * 
 * @param {colorObject} colorObject
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/color
 *   Examples of getting color object:
 *    `range.getBackgroundObjects()`
 *    `sheet.getTabColorObject()`
 * 
 * @param {theme} theme
 *  ## Need to pass theme in order to optimize calls to server
 *     `ss.getSpreadsheetTheme()`
 */
function convertColorObjectToHexColor_(colorObject, theme) {
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/color-type
  var colorTypeEnum = colorObject.getColorType().toString();
  switch (colorTypeEnum) {
    case 'UNSUPPORTED':
      return '';
    case 'RGB':
      return colorObject.asRgbColor().asHexString()
    case 'THEME':
      theme = theme || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTheme();
      // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/color-type.html
      var colorType = colorObject.asThemeColor().getThemeColorType();
      return theme.getConcreteColor(colorType).asRgbColor().asHexString();
    default:
      return 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

Test function:

```
function test_getHexColorFromColorObject(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range= ss.getRange("A1:D1");
  var colorObjects = range.getBackgroundObjects();
  var hexColor = convertColorObjectToHexColor_(colorObjects[0][0]);
  console.log(hexColor);
}
```